# How to use sender attributes in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using two buttons to do the same action. How can I identify which button was pressed using the "sender" from my `IBAction` function? (each button has a different Tag)

Here is what I want to do:

```
- (IBAction)addItemInParent:(id)sender {
  NSInteger choice = sender.tag;
}
```

I hope this question makes sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)addItemInParent:(id)sender 
{
    UIButton *buttonPressed = (UIButton *)sender;

    if (buttonPressed.tag == 123)
    {
        //button with tag 123 was pressed
    }else if (buttonPressed.tag == 124
    {
        //button with tag 124 was pressed
    }
}
```

Just replace my 123 and 124 with what the button tags actually are.

Answer (score 2):

If you are confident that this method is only invoked by a button press, then you can rewrite your method to this one:

```
- (IBAction)addItemInParent:(UIButton *)sender {
  NSInteger choice = sender.tag;
}
```

If not, check for the class of the sender:

```
- (IBAction)addItemInParent:(id)sender {
  if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSInteger choice = button.tag;
  }
  else {
    // handle other cases
  }      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After casting sender to UIButton, did you try:

```
if (choice == 101)
{
    // button whatever was pressed
}
else
{
    // the other button was pressed
}
```

Obviously you should use the tags you assigned to the buttons.

Comment: `(id)sender` does not have a `tag` property.

Comment: @CaptJak It's casted to a UIButton. Read before downvoting please.

Comment: I don't see it as being casted as a UIButton, neither in your post nor the OP. And although I wish all down votes were accompanied by a comment, it looks like yours was not since I am not the down-voter.

Comment: @CaptJak was looking at one of the answers instead of the OP's code. My humble apologies

Answer (score 1):

Change id to UIButton like so:

```
- (IBAction)addItemInParent:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSInteger choice = sender.tag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to
1) check if the id object is a actually UIView class or subclass
2) typecast the id object to UIView 
3) check the tag
4) decide what next based on the tag

```
if ([sender isKindOfClass:([UIView class])])
{
    NSInteger tag = ((UIView *)sender).tag;

    if (tag == <tag of button 1>)
    {
        //do something
    }
    else if (tag == <tag of button 2>)
    {
        //do something else
    }
}
```

You need to typecast because id can be any type of object and you must make sure that it is actually an instance of UIView class or subclass to be able to access the tag, as only UIView classes and subclasses have a tag property.

Comment: The OP says that he has two buttons, so casting and checking for UIView subclass is not necessary... Looking at the existing code, I would assume that the `IBAction` was created linking a `UIButton` object from the Storyboard.

Comment: The action itself belongs to the view controller. It is some logic in the controller layer. Apple choosing "id" makes very much sense. The controller layer should never depend on the presentation layer. 
Having it as id means when you change your presentation layer (replace buttons with something else), it will not break the action in the controller.
However, it is clear that anything on the screen will be a kind of UIView class. Thats why casting to the highest superclass.

Comment: True, and I am not saying that you are wrong. Your solution would continue to work even in the case of the UIButton being changed to anything else (in several of my own cases I have it as you described above). Strictly referring to the OP, though, he does say UIButton...